Calculate the frequency of transitions between geographical points
Background:
I have a data set of individuals moving between different fixed locations and I want to visualise the movement between them. I know how to draw lines between the points that an individual uses (see "current" pane of attached figure).
Problem:
Some individuals are repeatedly moving back and fourth between certain locations. I would like to indicate the frequency of repeated movement with varying thickness of the connectors between the dots (see "Desired" pane of figure 1). In other words: Individual 1 (red colour) is moving 2 times between point B and C (1B + 1C) and this line should be 2 times thicker than the line between point A and B which is covered 1 single time (1A).
Initial thoughts
As pointed out in a comment (on the original version of the question), the visualisation part is not the problem per se, as the thickness of the lines could be given by a "transition frequency" variable. It is the calculation of this variable that I need help with.
Question
How do I calculate the frequency of transitions between two points?
I would prefer an R-based solution but Qgis would also be very welcome.

Below is a toy set making the basic plot depicted in the left pane of figure 1 (without the desired variable thickness output).
# Load necessary packages:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Store data table with coordinates
movement <- read.table(
  textConnection(
    "ID; X; Y
    Individual_1; 7.5; 8.5
    Individual_1; 7.5; 7.5
    Individual_1; 8.5; 7.5
    Individual_1; 7.5; 7.5
    Individual_2; 7.0; 9.0
    Individual_2; 8.0; 9.0
    Individual_2; 8.0; 8.0
    Individual_2; 9.0; 8.0"),
  sep = ";", header = T) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# Convert to simple feature
movement <- movement %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"))

# Add the coordinates as columns X and Y (used during plotting)
movement <- movement %>% 
  bind_cols(st_coordinates(movement))

# Plot the coordinates and connections ("movement") between them.
ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = movement, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = ID), alpha=1, linewidth=2, show.legend = F) + # paths
  geom_sf(data = movement, size = 1.5, aes(), show.legend = F) + # points
  xlim(c(7,9)) + ylim(c(7,9)) +
  theme_classic() 


Just to get rid of an idea: I'd expect ggplot2 to handle this natively via linewidth aesthetics if your lines had some kind of a freq attribute indicating how often a path is repeated. The problem is, you're working with point data only being visualized as lines using geom_path(), as far as I understand. So first, I'd sf::st_cast() these to LINESTRINGS, probably, and use geom_sf() for visualization. Second, you need to determine freq. And maybe there is some approach/sf-extension/package existing in order to aggregate trajectories? r-spatial offers e.g. {spacetime}, {sftime}, ..

Thank you for thoughtful input! Yes, I believe you are completely right. The question is rather about how to obtain the frequency of a transition. I'll rephrase the question.
